# BS4 (BeautifulSoap) - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getText'

Tags: python-2.7, soap, beautifulsoup

I've been researching here and the solutions I found for my problem were unable to solve.

I'm trying to create a scraping of the Amazon page that captures the product's name and price, but as I try to run it, I always get the error:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getText'

What I find strange is that this error is intermittent, time works and time presents the error, I believe it is some way other than time to render the content for the soap.

I've already tried using time.sleep with a few seconds to try to circumvent this problem, but without success ...

Here is an excerpt from my code:

```
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

def StoreAmazon():

```
URL = ['www.amazon.com.br/Notebook-Acer-AN515-54-58CL-Endless-GTX1650/dp/B0883VMXX4?ref_=Oct_s9_apbd_otopr_hd_bw_bHrUqLT&pf_rd_r=1ZG49PCAZV8RN8CK6QDQ&pf_rd_p=ae2a6e14-5e57-57d1-a7c7-38f2deae6a08&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-10&pf_rd_t=BROWSE&pf_rd_i=16364755011','www.amazon.com.br/Monitor-Gamer-Samsung-LS24D332HSX-ZD/dp/B07MVPD3VK?ref_=Oct_s9_apbd_otopr_hd_bw_bHrUqbb&pf_rd_r=D34JDZ7EBFS7CTZ3X5CW&pf_rd_p=dfd6eead-be55-57b6-bdaf-226199170f0a&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-10&pf_rd_t=BROWSE&pf_rd_i=16364756011']

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0'}

for x in range(len(URL)):
    time.sleep(1)
    page = requests.get(URL[x], headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

    productName  = soup.find('span', {'id':'productTitle'}).getText()
    productPrice = soup.find('span', {'id':'priceblock_ourprice'}).getText()

    print (productName.strip())
    print (productPrice)
    print() 
    # converted_price = float(productPrice[0:5])
    # print (converted_price)
```

StoreAmazon()

Answer (score 0):

I printed the soup provided by your code. Amazon detected that it's an automated attempt and provided this notice

> To discuss automated access to Amazon data please contact api-services-support@amazon.com.
> For information about migrating to our APIs refer to our Marketplace APIs at https://developer.amazonservices.com/ref=rm_c_sv, or our Product Advertising API at https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html/ref=rm_c_ac for advertising use cases.

I could still fetch it using selenium:

```
URL = ['https://www.amazon.com.br/Notebook-Acer-AN515-54-58CL-Endless-GTX1650/dp/B0883VMXX4']

for x in range(len(URL)):
    soup = return_page_source_soup(URL[x])
    # print(soup)
    productName  = soup.find('span', {'class':'product-title-word-break'}).get_text(strip=True)
    print (productName)
```

it's my code for transferring source code from selenium to BeautifulSoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

chromeOptions = Options()
chromeOptions.headless = False
PATH = "D:\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=chromeOptions)
driver.set_page_load_timeout(20)

def return_page_source_soup(link):
    # pass
    while True:
        try:
            driver.get(link)
        except TimeoutException:
            print("timeout, retrying")
            continue
        else:
            break

    response = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response,"lxml")
    return soup
```

**Note 1:** You are inserting reference id in URL. it's not something constant. you have to remove from **?ref** from URL.

**Note 2:** Amazon has an affiliate program. so, I don't think you need to scrape data in this way from amazon.